# Error 403--Forbidden - web service error when I use SOAP UI

Tags: oracle, service, soapui, osb, bus

I created a WSDL Based Service in Oracle Service Bus 12c. 
I use HTTP protocol and I configured a Business Service, Proxy Service and Proxy Service pipeline...

When I use the testing tool of Oracle Service Bus, will test successful. when I invoke my web service using soapui I get an error like:

"Error 403--Forbidden

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable."

I don't know what is wrong with the configuration. 
Is anybody know why? Thank you!!

Regards...

Comment: Does the WSDL or the proxy have an OWSL policy attached to it? If not, did you specify a proxy-level security policy? Turn message and execution tracing on and see what it says.

Comment: How did you configure the SoapUI test? Did you import the service WSDL directly from OSB via http? Just checking if you are using the right URL.

Comment: I imported the service WSDL from OSB vía http.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and here is how to fix: in WebLogic console, remove the "API Manager Starter Application" deployment and restart OSB server, then it will work!

This issue might happen, as indicated in Oracle documentation, if you choose Oracle API Manager Template when setting up new domain.